# VS Code Django Debugger TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Using VS Code as my IDE for Django programming. I'm able to start my application via the integrated terminal by running 'python app/manage.py runserver 8000'. This starts no problem. In my launch.json file i have

```
"name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app/manage.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "8000",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
```

When i start debugging using F5 or the Debugger tab, the development server starts but then stops with the stack returning `raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name, tried=tried) django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: base.html`. Site loads with a server 500 error/I'm not sure if something with my path is off? Or theres a config error? Really need to use the build in debugger but can't figure out why it cant start the server when debugging. I've tried removing the args in the dev server `launch.json` but that doest work either. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is `base.html` in your project directory structure?

Comment: base:  app/apps/base/templates/base/base.html, manage.py /Users/charisse/Documents/GitHub/stem/app/manage.py

Comment: Nothing obvious to me as long as you're sure the environment you have selected in VS Code matches the one that `python` is pointing out when you run the command manually. Typically this means there's some configuration problem as the search path for templates is somehow different. Have you printed that out to see how they may differ?